# Footer div moves when zooming out

Tags: html, zooming

My footer div element moves to the right when zooming out. It is supposed to be like in the picture, the one with the blue letters.I need this to work for a larger screens[image: the problem]  `

```
        <div>
        <p class="">&copy; 2020 Pizza. All Rights Reserved</p>
        </div>`
```

And here is the css

```
footer div {
color: #0c648f;
font-size: 14px;
background-color: #f2f4f5;
padding: 1px 0;
margin-top: 10px;
```

}

```
footer p {
text-align: right;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the idea that it should be right-aligned to the page content? If so, you need a `max-width` on the `footer p` styles, so that the content will align to the right of that space rather than the right of the full page. You will need to center that element as well (using `margin: auto`).